# No entra al Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, codeigniter

Tengo un problema con una consulta Ajax a un controlador de *CodeIgniter*, resulta que no se esta ejecutando y mucho menos está llegando al controlador de *CodeIgniter*.

Cheque y no encuentro el error y mucho menos me esta mandando error. También me fije en la red del navegador y no se está ejecutando el Ajax.

Podrían apoyarme a encontrar la razón del porque no se está ejecutando el Ajax.

Les comparto mi código:

---

Función JavaScript con Ajax(“el alert si se muestra pero el Ajax no se ejecuta”):

```js
function getContratadosAjax() 
    {
      alert("entra");
      $('#tabla_personas_contratados').DataTable().destroy();

      var dt_contratados = $('#tabla_personas_contratados').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '<?= base_url();?>Personas/getContratadosAjax',
            "dataSrc": "",
            type : 'POST'
            },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id"},
            { data: null,
              render: function (data, type, row) {
              return row.apellido + ' ' + row.nombre;
            }},
            { "data": "legajo"},
            { "data": "grupo"},
            { "data": "cargo"},
            { "data": "dni"},
            { "data": "telefono"},
            {"render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              var html = `<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="getDocenteAjax(${row.id});" title="Eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="getUsuAdminAjax(${row.id});" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></div>`;
              
              return html;
            }},
        ]
      });

      // Enumero los registros de datatables
      dt_contratados.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
          dt_contratados.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
              cell.innerHTML = i+1;
          } );
      } ).draw();
      
    }
```

---

Controlador *CodeIgniter*:

```
function getContratadosAjax()
    {
        try {
            $elements = $this->Personas_model->getContratadosAjax(2);
            
            echo json_encode($elements);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
        } //./catch
    }
```

---

Vista HTML Tabla:

```html
<table id="tabla_personas_contratados" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>                             
                  <th>Apellido y Nombres</th>
                  <?php switch($rsTipo[0]->id){
                      case 1:
                          echo "<th>Legajo</th>";
                          echo "<th>Grupo</th>";
                          echo "<th>Cargo</th>";
                          break;
                      case 2:
                          echo "<th>Legajo</th>";
                          echo "<th>Proveedor</th>";
                          break;
                      case 3:
                          echo "<th>Legajo</th>";
                          echo "<th>Proveedor</th>";
                          break;
                      case 4:
                          echo "<th>Matrícula</th>";
                          break;
                      case 5:
                          break;
                  } ?>
                  <th>DNI</th>
                  <th>Teléfono</th>
                  <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
               
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

---

Resultado en navegador (tabla vacía):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente día.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: l[n] is undefined
    jQuery 8
    getContratadosAjax http://localhost/RegulusV/Personas/contratados:780
    <anonymous> http://localhost/RegulusV/Personas/contratados:669
    jQuery 13

Comment: Varias cosas que comentar. Cuándo y/o dónde se ejecuta la función JavaScript `getContratadosAjax()`? Fuera del contexto AJAX, qué estaría retornando la URL "<?= base_url();?>Personas/getContratadosAjax" (desconozco qué retornaría base_url())?. Y ya que estás llamando información, recomendaría configurar el endpoint como GET en lugar de POST. Por otro lado, ya que retornas y usas el objecto completo, removería `dataSrc`

Comment: Ese error me esta mandado el Ajax

Comment: @KBeDev; @Triby les comparto el error.

Comment: Edite la publicación y les mostré el error que me manda.

Comment: Esta muy raro porque es estoy utilizando algo igual en otra función y ahí si se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: @Javierfr, ¿Existe la tabla antes de ejecutar esa función? Tal vez solo necesitas poner el script hasta el final, antes de `</body>`. La otra opción es que CodeIgniter esté devolviendo una respuesta con error en lugar del JSON que esperas. Revisa la consola, hay una opción para analizar las peticiones y respuestas, generalmente ahí encuentras información útil.

Comment: Por lo que indican los errores, la consulta se realiza. Sin embargo, lo que recibe DataTables no es lo esperado/configurado para ser manejado. Creo que primero, como mencioné antes, prueba llamar a la URL de retorna los datos a tu objeto DataTables pero fuera de ese contexto, o bien, revisa el log de la consulta, puede que sea un error de enrutador, lo que puede estar retornando un text/html, error 504 o alguna otra cosa. Si estás usando un navegador Chromium, prueba habilitar el logging de las XMLHttpRequests, o, si estás usando Firefox, revisa la pestaña de redes (habilitando XHR)

Comment: De cualquier forma, te sugiero que registres la ruta con método GET y trates de ingresar a `http://ruta-de-tu-proyecto/Personas/getContratadosAjax` para ver lo que está pasando. Una vez que lo corrijas, puedes volver a registrar con POST y comenzar a integrar en AJAX.

Comment: @Triby de echo no se esta ejecutando el Ajax porque cuando doy inspeccionar elemento y no me sale la petición en la Red.

Comment: @Triby Lo sé, pero está vacía. De allí mi comentario

Comment: Cambie el POST por GET y aun me sale ese mismo error.

Comment: @Javierfr Puedes intentar llamar primero al endpoint, guardar la respuesta, y luego cargarla en el objeto DataTables

Comment: @KBeDev, interpreté mal tu comentario, lo siento.

Comment: @KBeDev como que endpoint? Les comento tambien que si llamo a la funcion del controlado de forma tipica con el Ajax si entra, pero de la forma que la tengo armada yo no, pero esta muy raro porque de esa forma la tengo igual en otra funcion y si funciona.

Comment: @Javierfr [Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints)